# Is a multi-way join at all possible using CouchDB views?

Tags: couchdb

JOINING data in a 'sql-esque' way is possible within MapReduce as mentioned in many places - such as [these Standford course notes](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/book.pdf), and [this MSc thesis](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/publications/thesis/online/IM100859.pdf), and a [plagiarized copy of that thesis](http://ijniet.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/7.pdf) published by http://ijniet.org :p.

I have 3 Entities:

1. `A`
2. `B`
3. `C`

`A` and `B` can be joined on column `ab`, and `BC` can be joined on column `bc`. I *think* that I can achieve this via cascading MapReduce tasks. But that I CAN'T do that in CouchDB in any way, whether that is with Map functions, reduce functions, list functions (that consume a MapReduce view), or a combination of these...

In CouchDB you could output documents of different entities with the same join key. But as far as I can tell there is no possible map function that allows for grouping multiple entities by either the same key, or a key range?

This is specifically for JOINS where Foreign key columns are different for each join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do cascade joins in CouchDB.

The only joins that you can do are one-to-many joins.

It consists of a view that emits the linked documents as a value:

```
function(doc){
    emit([doc._id,0]);
    emit([doc.ab,1],{_id:doc.ab});
}
```

---

Then you query with `?include_docs=true`

You would get something like this:

```
{rows:[
    {key:["my_main_doc_id",0],doc:{my main document...}},
    {key:["my_main_doc_id",1],doc:{child doc...}}
]}
```

See this [documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Linked_documents)

Comment: This looks like you are creating your entity relationship within the doc itself. You can also approximate joins by emitting docs of different entity types with the same key, then retrieving a grouped map index. But I'm realizing that you can't do the actual join in the reduce function since you need to allow for rereduce=true